# Laravel Type error: Too few arguments to function

Tags: laravel-5.5

I created a controller with an index controller :

```
public function index(EntityRepository $vcs, EntityRepository $vcskns)
{
    $entitiesLists = $vcs->getEntities();
    $entitiesWithKnLists = $vcskns->getEntitiesWithKeyneeds();

    return view('admin.home', compact('entitiesLists', 'entitiesWithKnLists'));
}
```

In EntityRepository I created getEntitiesWithKeyneeds :

```
public function getEntitiesWithKeyneeds()
{
    $valuechains = Valuechain::orderBy('valuechains.id')
        ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
        ->join('langs', 'lang_valuechain.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
        ->where('langs.isMainlanguage', '=', '1')
        ->with('segments')
        ->with('keyneeds')
        ->withCount('segments')
        ->withCount('keyneeds')
        ->get();


    foreach ($valuechains as $valuechain) {
        $ids[] = $valuechain->id;
    }

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $vcskns[] = Segment::select(
            'lang_valuechain.vcname', 'lang_valuechain.vcshortname',
            'lang_segment.segname', 'lang_segment.segshortname', 'segments.id',
            'lang_segment.created_at', 'lang_segment.updated_at', 'lang_segment.deleted_at'
        )
            ->distinct()
            ->withCount('keyneeds')
            ->join('lang_segment', 'segments.id', '=', 'lang_segment.segment_id')
            ->join('valuechains', 'segments.valuechain_id', '=', 'valuechains.id')
            ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
            ->join('sectors', 'valuechains.sector_id', '=', 'sectors.id')
            ->join('lang_sector', 'sectors.id', '=', 'lang_sector.sector_id')
            ->join('langs', 'lang_valuechain.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
            ->where([
                ['langs.isMainlanguage', '=', '1'],
                ['valuechains.id', '=', $id]
            ])
            ->whereNull('valuechains.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('sectors.deleted_at')
            ->whereNull('segments.deleted_at')
            ->get();

    }
    return $vcskns;
}
```

I receive an error message :

Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\BackOffice\StatsController::index(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

I wish i could solve this issue.

Another issue would be to know how i could force every views of my backend to have the returns of my EntityRepository. theorirically i have to declare my variables in all my methods ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create an interface this way :

```
<?php
    namespace App\Contracts;

    interface EntityInterface {
        public function getEntities();
        public function getEntitiesWithKeyneeds();
}
```

My EntityRepository looks like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\BackOffice\Repository;

use App\Contracts\EntityInterface;
use App\Segment;
use App\Valuechain;


class EntityRepository implements EntityInterface
{
    public function getEntities()
    {
        $vcs = Valuechain::select('valuechains.id', 'lang_valuechain.vcname',     
                    'lang_valuechain.vcshortname')
                    ->withCount('segments')
                    ->join('sectors', 'valuechains.sector_id', '=', 'sectors.id')
                    ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
                    ->join('langs', 'lang_valuechain.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
                    ->where('langs.isMainlanguage', '=', '1')
                    ->whereNull('valuechains.deleted_at')
                    ->whereNull('sectors.deleted_at')
                    ->get();

        return $vcs;
    }

    public function getEntitiesWithKeyneeds()
    {
        // liste des cdv
        $valuechains = Valuechain::orderBy('valuechains.id')
                ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
                ->join('langs', 'lang_valuechain.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
               ->where('langs.isMainlanguage', '=', '1')
                ->with('segments')
                ->with('keyneeds')
                ->withCount('segments')
                ->withCount('keyneeds')
                ->get();

        foreach ($valuechains as $valuechain) {
            $ids[] = $valuechain->id;
        }

        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $vcskns[] = Segment::select(
                'lang_valuechain.vcname', 'lang_valuechain.vcshortname',
                'lang_segment.segname', 'lang_segment.segshortname', 'segments.id',
                'lang_segment.created_at', 'lang_segment.updated_at', 
                'lang_segment.deleted_at'
            )
                ->distinct()
                ->withCount('keyneeds')
                ->join('lang_segment', 'segments.id', '=', 'lang_segment.segment_id')
                ->join('valuechains', 'segments.valuechain_id', '=', 'valuechains.id')
                ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
                ->join('sectors', 'valuechains.sector_id', '=', 'sectors.id')
                ->join('lang_sector', 'sectors.id', '=', 'lang_sector.sector_id')
                ->join('langs', 'lang_valuechain.lang_id', '=', 'langs.id')
                ->where([
                    ['langs.isMainlanguage', '=', '1'],
                    ['valuechains.id', '=', $id]
                ])
                ->whereNull('valuechains.deleted_at')
                ->whereNull('sectors.deleted_at')
                ->whereNull('segments.deleted_at')
                ->get();
        }
        return $vcskns;

    }
}
```

In app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php I had to bind the interfaces. I guess I have to  overwrite the constructor from use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider :

```
public function __construct($app)
{
    $this->app = $app;

    $this->app->bind(
        'App\Contracts\EntityInterface',
        'App\Http\Controllers\BackOffice\Repository\EntityRepository'
    );
}
```

And my controller where I use those values look like this (here is my index method) :

```
public function index(EntityInterface $vcs)
{
    $entitiesLists = $vcs->getEntities();
    $entitiesWithKnLists = $vcs->getEntitiesWithKeyneeds();

    return view('admin.home', compact('entitiesLists', 'entitiesWithKnLists'));
}
```